# Django: Use post() in UpdateView to populate form's fields with instance's existing field values

Tags: python, django

I have trouble getting the current instance's fields on my UpdateView. How do I get the specific instance based on its id?

**views.py**

```
class ShowUpdate(UpdateView):
  model = Show
  fields = ['description', 'season', 'episode']

  def post(self, request, **kwargs):
      request.POST = request.POST.copy()
      request.POST['description'] = "how to get instance description?" # problem here
      request.POST['season'] = 2
      return super(ShowUpdate, self).post(request, **kwargs)
```

**models.py**

```
class Show(models.Model):
  owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, default=True, related_name='o')
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  description = models.TextField(default='N/A', blank=True, max_length=250)
  season = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  episode = models.IntegerField(default=0)

  def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('show:index')

  def __str__(self):
      return self.title
```

Comment: You can access to instance by call the `self.get_object()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Look to the [UpdateView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.10/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/) docs

This View has method `get_object(self, queryset=None)`

In you case just need to call it in `POST` method something like this:

```
class ShowUpdate(UpdateView):
  model = Show
  fields = ['description', 'season', 'episode']

  def post(self, request, **kwargs):
      self.object = self.get_object()
      request.POST = request.POST.copy()
      request.POST['description'] = self.object.description
      request.POST['season'] = 2
      return super(ShowUpdate, self).post(request, **kwargs)
```